# Is it possible to use wildcards in org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra in Felix?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

Is it possible to use wildcards in org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra in Felix?

For example, I want to export to the org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra packages like my.package.* .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not. The specification literally states:

> Packages specified in this property are added to the org.osgi.framework.system.packages property and therefore have the same syntax. This allows the configurator to only define the additional packages and leave the standard VM packages to be defined by the framework.